# Why nginx redirect zh_cn to zh_cn/?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I write nginx configuration file like below, when I enter url http://xxx/zh_cn, it will redirect to http://xxx/zh_cn/ , but if I remove "if (-d $request_filename){}", nginx will not redirect the path, why ?

```
location = / {
    if ($http_accept_language ~* ^zh-cn) {
        set $lang zh_cn;
        rewrite ^/$ /$lang/index.html redirect;
    }
}

location / {
   if (-d $request_filename){}
   try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html /abc/$uri;
}
```

I know the code "rewrite ^/(.*)([^/])$ http://$host/$1$2/ permanent" can redirect the path, but why just "if (-d $request_filename){}" also work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third example from [If is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil#Examples).

In this case, your `try_files` is ignored and nginx's default behaviour to redirect to URL with slash if it sees request without slash that matches directory.